# How to add text to a JComboBox when using IntelliJ UI Designer?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jcombobox

Using code generated by IntelliJ's UI Designer, and trying to add text values to a JComboBox doesn't work for me.

I've created a brand new, empty project, where I created a new GUI form from the Swing GUI Designer menu. So now I have a panel I named "mainPanel", and I added a JComboBox to it, and I've generated the main method.
So now I have this code:

```
public class CmbBox {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JComboBox comboBox1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CmbBox");
        frame.setContentPane(new CmbBox().mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

How should I add values to the combobox in this case?
In Eclipse this was the easiest thing ever, but in IntelliJ I either get a data binding error, or it runs but the combobox is still empty.
I couldn't even find a properly working code on Google or anywhere for that matter, or should I just not generate the main when using a JComboBox?

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution? Does it help?

Comment: Yes it's working, it was so easy I can't believe I couldn't make it work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the constructor to the class and add items to the `JComboBox` from there:

```
    public CmbBox() {
        comboBox1.addItem("hello");
        comboBox1.addItem("world");
    }
```

[image: combobox]